# Why are these flash messages only working when I manually refresh the page? (ExpressJs)

Tags: node.js

I am currently working on this website and for some reason, it is ONLY with these 2 flash messages that don't work as wanted.

I have them written the same way as all my others that work.

```
            req.flash('success_msg', 'You have been registered successfully, you may now login');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
```

Is it because I HAVE to redirect?

I have to manually refresh the browser page for them to appear for some reason, anyone can help? I have made some research on it and I haven't found this exact problem.

```
    if(count > 0){

    req.flash('error_msg', 'Username already exists');
    res.render('register'); 

}else{

    User.count({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, count2){

    if(count2 > 0){

        req.flash('error_msg', 'Email already exists');
        res.render('register');
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I feel so stupid, I even answered my own question in there.

```
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Email already exists');
        res.redirect('/users/register');
```

I did have to redirect instead of rendering.

Sorry for the useless post.